# Redux ToolKit Query - Make multiple queries in the same component dependant on each other

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to use RTK Query in a NextJS app to fetch multiple entities from an API. I have the `App` and `AppVersion` models. When the component loads I need to fetch the `App` and then fetch the appropriate `AppVersion`s. An `App` has the `currentVersionId` property that links to and `AppVersion`.

The code fails because the component is rendered without the router at first, it can't get an app and there's no `app.currentversionId`.

I have two slices that fetch the appropriate objects from a RESTful API.

```js
function AppsShow() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query
  const { data: app } = useGetAppQuery(parseInt(id, 10)) // from RTK Query slice
  const currentVersion = useGetVersionQuery(app?.currentVersionId) // from RTK Query slice

  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}
```

What is the appropriate pattern to use here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Use the `skip` option :)

```js
function AppsShow() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query
  const { data: app } = useGetAppQuery(parseInt(id, 10)) // from RTK Query slice
  const currentVersion = useGetVersionQuery(app?.currentVersionId, { skip: !app?.currentVersionId })

  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}
```

Alternatively you could use the `skipToken` that is also exported by RTK-Query (this approach might play better with TypeScript)

```js
function AppsShow() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query
  const { data: app } = useGetAppQuery(parseInt(id, 10)) // from RTK Query slice
  const currentVersion = useGetVersionQuery(app?.currentVersionId ?? skipToken)

  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}
```